# Ejabberd, Python: Check user, if not create

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd

Is it possible to talk to an Ejabberd interface from python through and xmpp client like sleekxmpp to create a user if it does not exist?

Can someone advice the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check in-band registration already ?
The specification is here: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html

If you configure ejabberd to allow in-band registration, then your client will be able to create an account if it does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

If Twisted is an option for you, you can adapt my [jarn.xmpp.twisted](https://github.com/ggozad/jarn.xmpp.twisted) to your needs. It makes use of [XEP-0133 Service Administration](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0133.html). The relevant pieces can be found in [protocols.py](https://github.com/ggozad/jarn.xmpp.twisted/blob/master/jarn/xmpp/twisted/protocols.py).